# How to import or assign metadata to the vertices of a SpiecEasi network in R

Tags: r, network-programming, bioinformatics

I had some issues regarding the making of a network! in particular, I want to insert in the attributes of the vertexes the metadata stored in the object used to make the network itself!

I was thinking that with the attributes of the type of substrata (the metadata I want to visualize) I will be able to visualize and therefore validate the idea that the clusters are different in function of the substrata and that some particular organisms can function as a bridge through the clusters.

Here is what I made so far:

```
# I started importing the phyloseq obj in a tse obj
library(NetCoMi)
library(mia)
tse<- makeTreeSEFromPhyloseq(SEps17)

# Agglomerate to genus level
tse <- agglomerateByRank(tse, rank = "Genus") #in teoria ho gia' fatto

# Add relative abundances
tse <- transformCounts(tse, assay.type = "counts", method = "relabundance", MARGIN = "samples") 

# Filter by prevalence
tse <- subsetByPrevalentFeatures(tse,
                                 prevalence = 0.01,
                                 detection = 0,
                                 assay.type = "relabundance")

# Add log10-transformed abundances
tse <- transformCounts(tse, assay.type="counts", 
                       method = "log10", pseudocount = 1)

# Add clr-transformed abundances
tse <- transformCounts(tse, assay.type="counts",
                       method = "clr", pseudocount = 1)

dim(tse)

# then the spieceasi function
se_mb_est<- spiec.easi(
  t(assay(tse, "counts")),
  method = "mb",
  sel.criterion = "stars",
  verbose = TRUE,
  pulsar.select = TRUE,
  pulsar.params = list(rep.num = 999, ncores=40)     )

# extract matrices
se_mb_cor <- as.matrix(getOptBeta(se_mb_est))
se_mb_corS <- as.matrix(symBeta(se_mb_cor))
rownames(se_mb_corS) <- colnames(se_mb_corS) <- rownames(tse)
se_mb_corS<- abs(se_mb_corS)

net_hmp_16S_prot <- netConstruct(data = se_mb_corS,
                                 dataType = "condDependence", 
                                 sparsMethod = "none")
netprops_hmp_16S_prot <- netAnalyze(net_hmp_16S_prot, hubPar = "eigenvector", clustMethod =  "cluster_fast_greedy")
```

I tried the adj2igraph function but the result is the same because I do not know how.

I would simply highlight somehow in the network the information on the substrata of the different samples. I'm sure that this is a possible thing to do but in all these functions I cannot find the parameter to use.